# How to get '?' and '=' in a url?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal and to web development. I'm very surprised I have not been able to find the answer to this with 2 hours of looking.

I'm using Drupal 7 and putting the below php into a tpl.php file.
The `?` is printing as `%3F` and the `=` is printing as `%3D`.

```
<?php print l("link name", "relationship/".$user->uid."/request/1?destination=user/".$user->uid); ?>
```

What I need is: `http://example.com/relationship/42/request/1?destination=user/42`.

Comment: What you want there is quite unusual, why not `?destination_user=42`?

Comment: I got the url from hovering over a link in a block that comes with the Drupal User Relationships module. Perhaps _ instead of = would work. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to add a query string to the URL, which means you need to pass the query string parameters as part of the [`$options` argument to the `l` function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7).

In particular you need to pass the [`'query'` option inherited from the `url` function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7)

```
l('link name', "relationship/{$user->uid}/request/1", array(
    'query' => array(
        'destination' => "user/{$user->uid}"
    )
);
```